# How to check the similarity between two ints java

Tags: java, android

I am trying to create an app where the user has to memorize a `random number` (17 digits long) and then enter what she/he remembers.

After generating the number, *how do I check how similar they are i.e. 10 of the digits match so it is 58% similar*.

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: 17 digits its too long for an int,

Comment: Do you want to consider 9123456799 to be similar to 8812345678 because of the identical substring, even though none of the digits match in the corresponding positions?

Comment: No, 9123456799 and 8812345678 would not be similar. So it would be a 0% match

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lets say you compare this two strings:

```
String number1; // users number
String number2; // your number
```

Since you said both will be 17 digit long, no need to take in account different sizes (then you should go from the end):

```
int matches = 0;
for (int i = 0;  i < number1.length(); i++) {
    if (number1.substring(i, i + 1).equals(number2.substring(i, i + 1))) matches++;
}
```

Another approach would be with char arrays:

```
char[] charArray1 = number1.toCharArray();
char[] charArray2 = number2.toCharArray();
for (int i = 0; i < charArray1.length; i++) {
    if (charArray1[i] == charArray2[i]) matches++;
}
```

Or by using Strings own array of chars (thanks @David Wallace):

```
for (int i = 0; i < charArray1.length; i++) {
    if (number1.charAt(i) == number2.charAt(i)) matches++;
}
```

Now, you calculate procent:

```
double procent = matches / (number1.length() * 1d) * 100;
```

You must multiply with double value of `1`, so it doesn't calculates with `int`, this will force it to deal with doubles.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Very useful

Answer (score 0):

you can use integer(or long) division and modulo to get the digits of an int.
See this java snippet:

```
int num1=1234;
int dig[]=new int[4];

dig[3]=num1       /1000;
dig[2]=(num1%1000)/100;
dig[1]=(num1%100) /10;
dig[0]=(num1%10)  /1;

for(int i=0;i<4;i++){
    System.out.println("dig"+i+" : "+dig[i]);
}
```

It will print:

```
dig0 : 4
dig1 : 3
dig2 : 2
dig3 : 1
```